# Reading in JSON through Angular Resources Service

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

How can I use `angular-resources.js` to read in a JSON file through a service?

I am working on a very basic Angular app for testing purposes and am just trying to read in data from JSON file right now.  I am placing this code in a service so I can more easily swap it out when we move a server based data store.

My `App` and `App.controller` declaration are as follows:

```
'use strict';

// create module for custom directives
var App = angular.module('App', ['jsonService']);

// controller business logic
App.controller('AppCtrl', function AppCtrl($scope, JsonService) {
    console.log("marker 1");

    if (!$scope.jsonData) {
        console.log("marker 2");
        JsonService.getData(function (d) {
            console.log(d);
            $scope.jsonData = d;
            $scope.records = d.length;
        });
    } else {
        console.log("I have data already... " + $scope.jsonData);
    }

    console.log($scope.jsonData);
});
```

My `JsonService` is defined as the follow, at the moment:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('jsonService', ['ngResource'])
.factory('JsonService', function($resource, $filter) {
    // define the remote service using Angular's $resource module
    var service = $resource('/data/ProcessModeling-Resources.json', {});

    var JsonService = {
        // calls $resource.query() to retrieve the remote data.
        getData : function getData(callback) {
            console.log("marker 3");
            service.query(function (data) {
                console.log("marker 4");
            });
        }
    };

    return JsonService;
});
```

The console output I am getting follows:

```
marker 1 app.js:8
marker 2 app.js:11
marker 3 services.js:13
undefined app.js:21
TypeError: Object #<Resource> has no method 'push'
    at copy (http://127.0.0.1:8000/lib/angular.js:556:21)
    at new Resource (http://127.0.0.1:8000/lib/angular-resource.js:330:9)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8000/lib/angular-resource.js:386:32
    at forEach (http://127.0.0.1:8000/lib/angular.js:117:20)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8000/lib/angular-resource.js:385:19
    at wrappedCallback (http://127.0.0.1:8000/lib/angular.js:6650:59)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8000/lib/angular.js:6687:26
    at Object.Scope.$eval (http://127.0.0.1:8000/lib/angular.js:7840:28)
    at Object.Scope.$digest (http://127.0.0.1:8000/lib/angular.js:7707:25)
    at Object.Scope.$apply (http://127.0.0.1:8000/lib/angular.js:7926:24) angular.js:5582
```

I'm receiving my error when I attempt to call my `service.query(function (data) { }`, which (if I'm understanding correctly) should be pulling my JSON file in.

I've been using [AngularJS Cats App](http://ericterpstra.com/apps/jsCats/ngCatsHOM/) as an example for pulling data.

Comment: I presume that the data in your file is not an array as required by the query() method.

Comment: `data` is an `object`.  It has two fields: {'name': 'Resources', 'children': [ ... ] }.  There is an array in there... would that be causing my pain?

Comment: Yes, the response needs to be an array, top level, not wrapped in an object.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I'd follow @pkozlowski's advice and make sure the response is an array. Anyway, here's an example that loads data from a JSON file similar to what you describe in your comments. It uses **ngResource** and can help you put things together: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ofq7Md8udEnIhAPF1NgL?p=preview

The service

```
angular.module('jsonService', ['ngResource'])
.factory('JsonService', function($resource) {
  return $resource('cats.json',{ }, {
    getData: {method:'GET', isArray: false}
  });
});
```

Notice that `isArray` is set to `false`.

Your app and controller

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['jsonService']);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, JsonService){
  JsonService.getData(function(data){
    $scope.name = data.name;
    $scope.children = data.children;
  });
});
```

`getData` is actually not needed since the **Resource** class gives you some useful convenience methods such a `get`, you can just do this

```
angular.module('jsonService', ['ngResource'])
.factory('JsonService', function($resource) {
  return $resource('cats.json');
});

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, JsonService){
  JsonService.get(function(data){
    $scope.name = data.name;
    $scope.children = data.children;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @jm-.  It still took me a bit to figure it out, but I got it!  I am still wondering though -- are `get` and `query` the same, except that `query` expects an array, while `get` does not?

Comment: They are similar in the sense that both make `GET` requests, but you `get` one resource `{}` and `query` multiple resources `[{},{}]`.