# How to connect and put in JSON instead of mongolab in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, mlab

I want to use JSON instead of MongoLab example shown on AngularJS website.
Here's the code from the website:

```
angular.module('mongolab', ['ngResource']).
factory('Project', function($resource) {
  var Project = $resource('https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases' +
      '/angularjs/collections/projects/:id',
      { apiKey: '4f847ad3e4b08a2eed5f3b54' }, {
        update: { method: 'PUT' }
      }
  );
```

Is there any way I could connect and put into JSON file available on my folder instead of hosting it to MongoLab?
Any response would be really appreciated!

Comment: I tried using var Project = $resource('test.json'). It didn't work. I think I didn't understand clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at this example:

[Reading in JSON through Angular Resources Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13849902/reading-in-json-through-angular-resources-service)

You want to return the Project variable from your factory

```
var Project = $resource('test.json', {} );
return Project;
```

then use it in the controller after you inject it:

```
Project.get(function(data){
  $scope.bar = data.foo;
});
```

Update:
After looking thru the 1.1.3 angular-resource.js code, it looks like it always does an http request to get its data. Set up a simple RoR app with a REST interface for testing.

Or use plunker (like the linked question above) for complete remote testing.

Comment: Thank you so much flim! I tried that and put this in controller function ListCtrl($scope, Project) {
  Project.get(function(data) {
  $scope.projects = Project.query();
  });
}
It doesn't show the entry I have in JSON. Also can we use Project.put to push data to test.json?

Comment: You won't be able to put/push. Did you have the file in the correct directory? Try using an absolute path.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried using absolute path, it is just able to show blank page, no values. So is there any way, I can post values .json file on the current directory?

Comment: After looking thru the 1.1.3 angular-resource.js code, it looks like it always does an http request to get its data. Set up a simple RoR app with a REST interface for testing.