# How to service call using angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, service, restangular

I have the following json data service file.

```
    {
        "id": "exam_history:exam_colon",
        "text": "When was the last time you had a screening for colon cancer?",
        "answer": {
            "selectType": "single",
            "choice": [
                {
                    "description": "Never",
                    "value": "never",
                    "image": "icon-remove"
                },
                {
                    "description": "Past 2 years",
                    "value": "past_24_months",
                    "image": "cg-icon-2less"
                },
                {
                    "description": "2-5 years ago",
                    "value": "2-5_years",
                    "image": "cg-icon-2-5"
                },
                {
                    "description": "5+ years ago",
                    "value": "5+_years",
                    "image": "cg-icon-5plus"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

I want to use angular js to pull this question and present it on the view. Can someone show me how it can be done using angular creating a dummy service and using this to show on the view??

Comment: Take a look at Angular's $http service: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: use a resource like: [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13849902/reading-in-json-through-angular-resources-service) or a service like: [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161537/angularjs-load-data-from-service)